# Quotient field of ring of regular functions at some point in affine variety is the field of rational functions on the variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Hartshorne's book of Algebraic Geometry. I am stuck in understanding why quotient field of the local domain $O_p$ (where $O_p$ denotes the ring of regular functions at a point $p$ in affine variety $Y$) is the field of rational functions $K(Y)$.

I need some help to understand this.
Thanks

Comment: He proves this, doesn't he? What part is unclear?

Comment: On page 17 he wrote every rational function in K(Y) is in some O_p. How it gives K(Y) as quotient field of O_p is my question

Comment: Everything is taking place inside of the field $K(Y)$. At this point he has established that all the $A(Y) \subseteq \mathcal O_P$ have the same quotient field, let's call it $L$, inside $K(Y)$. The only remaining worry is that $K(Y)$ might be strictly bigger than $L$.

Comment: Exactly i agree with you

Comment: Do you agree that he resolves this issue? He takes any element of $K(Y)$ and shows that it lies in some $\mathcal O_P \subseteq L$.

Comment: But we don't know that the quotient field of the O_p's for p in Y are same , only know that they are isomorphic and then can't say all O_p are contained in L

Answer (score 2):

For a domain $A$, the quotient field of $A$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for any prime $\mathfrak{p}$. This is because taking the quotient field of a domain is simply localizing at the prime ideal $(0)$, and in the case above, localizing at $\mathfrak{p}$ then localizing at $(0)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the same as just localizing at $(0)$.

Comment: We know O_p is subring of the field K(Y), but how the localization of O_p gives K(Y) to be O _p 's quotient field is not clear

Comment: Without even considering properties of localization, I think you just stated another way to see the answer. $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a subring of $k$, the quotient field pf $A$. Thus its quotient field is contained in $k$. Try to prove the other containment.

Comment: Asking this question basically i asked about the reverse containment that you asked me to try